# API that returns XML. Can I use XmlTextWriter and would this be faster than creating an XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, api

Currently writing an .ashx file that returns some XML. Here is what I am essentially doing in the `ProcessRequest` sub

```
Dim xml As XmlDocument = getXML(context.Request.QueryString("products"))
xml.Save(context.Response.Output)
```

I was wondering if I could also somehow use an `XmlTextWriter` and if so would this be better/faster?

Speed is by far the most important factor but I'm very new to programming in VB.net so if there's anything else I should know that would be useful please let me know.

---

Xml content incase anyone is interested...It's this but with the possibility of returning up to 46 products.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
      <product>
        <id>58</id>
        <prices />
        <instock>True</instock>
        <shipping> - This product will ship today if ordered within the next 2 hours and 46 minutes.</shipping>
      </product>
      <product>
        <id>59</id>
        <prices />
        <instock>False</instock>
        <shipping>This product will be in stock soon</shipping>
      </product>
</products>
```

Comment: I think the body of the method getXml() is needed to be able to tell.

Comment: Not sure why you need xml in this case.  I would just take the QueryString and save as a file with a xml extension.

Comment: Why is speed important? Is it not running fast enough?

Comment: Well if `getXML` returns an `XmlDocument` then the `Save` call is fine, I would however use `xml.Save(context.Response.OutputStream)` as that way the XML document would be properly encoded according to the XML declaration in the document.

Comment: @spender Speed is always important on a website! It's very fast, but this is going to get called a lot so I want to make sure it is as efficient as possible.

Comment: @MartinHonnen it does indeed return an XmlDocument and thanks for the tip about writing to the OutputStream!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the first concern is how you serialize the XML. A maximum amount of 46 products does not seem to be a very large amount of data, so the effects of serializing faster or handling memory more efficiently are not too big.

Instead, I'd propose to cache the output if possible. If the data are not user-dependent and do not change to frequently, you could store the result in the cache and serve it from there. Instead of storing the XmlDocument in cache, store the serialized version so that you only need to write the string to the response. The following sample shows how to use the cache:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string productsKey = context.Request.QueryString("products");
    string cacheKey = "Products_" + productsKey;
    if (context.Cache[cacheKey] == null)
    {
        // lockObj declared on class level as 
        // private static readonly lockObj = new object();
        lock(lockObj)             {
            if (context.Cache[cacheKey] == null)
            {
                 using(StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
                 {
                     var doc = getXml(productskey);
                     doc.Save(writer);
                     // Set caching options as required
                     context.Cache.Add(cacheKey, writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString(), null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
                 }
            }
        }
        context.Response.Write(context.Cache[cacheKey]);
        return;
    }
```

For details on the Cache class see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks I am going to look into this. Could you explain the reasoning for calling lock()? Is this to ensure the data gets added to the cache before the processRequest completes and returns?

Comment: You're welcome. The `lock` is to ensure that the data is added to the cache only once even if there are parallel requests.